# How does the link type "adjusted complete" work for agglomerative hierachical clustering in WEKA?

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, hierarchical-clustering

The only descriptions I can find about "adjusted complete" linkage say something like: "same as complete linkage, but with largest within cluster distance"

What is meant by "within cluster distance"?

How is the distance between two clusters finally calculated using this linkage approach?

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great things about open-source software is that you can find out exactly how the software works. The code below shows [Weka's source code](https://svn.scms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/clusterers/HierarchicalClusterer.java) of the `HierarchicalClusterer` algorithm, more specifically it shows the part which implements the `COMPLETE` and `ADJCOMPLETE` functionality. The difference is as follows:

- Just like the `COMPLETE` linkage method, compute the maximum distance between one node from cluster 1 and one node from cluster 2 and store this in `fBestDist`
- Then, find the largest distance between nodes within cluster 1 or cluster 2 and store this in `fMaxDist`
- Finally subtract `fMaxDist` from `fBestDist`

So the distance between two clusters calculated using `ADJCOMPLETE` as `linkType` corresponds to the `COMPLETE` distance minus the largest distance between 2 nodes within either cluster 1 or cluster 2.

`Adjusted Complete-Link` was proposed in the following [paper](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%22adjusted%20complete%22&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CEIQFjAB&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.11.4772&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=RBEkUOivCdDwsgb77oGYDQ&usg=AFQjCNFRK0mYN1JNhLYbz1hyL0PeBmnolw&cad=rja):

> Sepandar Kamvar, Dan Klein and Christopher Manning (2002). *Interpreting and Extending Classical Agglomerative Clustering Algorithms Using a Model-Based Approach*. In Proceedings of 19th International Conference on Machine Learning (ICML-2002)

According to it (section 4.2), `Adjusted Complete-Link` is a version of `Complete-Link` which should be used if the clusters having varying radii (see Figure 10).

```java
case COMPLETE:
case ADJCOMLPETE:
  // find complete link distance aka maximum link, which is the largest distance between
  // any item in cluster1 and any item in cluster2
  fBestDist = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < cluster1.size(); i++) {
    int i1 = cluster1.elementAt(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < cluster2.size(); j++) {
      int i2 = cluster2.elementAt(j);
      double fDist = fDistance[i1][i2];
      if (fBestDist < fDist) {
        fBestDist = fDist;
      }
    }
  }
  if (m_nLinkType == COMPLETE) {
    break;
  }
  // calculate adjustment, which is the largest within cluster distance
  double fMaxDist = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < cluster1.size(); i++) {
    int i1 = cluster1.elementAt(i);
    for (int j = i+1; j < cluster1.size(); j++) {
      int i2 = cluster1.elementAt(j);
      double fDist = fDistance[i1][i2];
      if (fMaxDist < fDist) {
        fMaxDist = fDist;
      }
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < cluster2.size(); i++) {
    int i1 = cluster2.elementAt(i);
    for (int j = i+1; j < cluster2.size(); j++) {
      int i2 = cluster2.elementAt(j);
      double fDist = fDistance[i1][i2];
      if (fMaxDist < fDist) {
        fMaxDist = fDist;
      }
    }
  }
  fBestDist -= fMaxDist;
  break;
```